# How to make equal sign do repetitive calculation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Brief Description: I am trying to make a basic calculator using html and JavaScript. So far I have successfully done all the basic functionality of a calculator with the number, operators, decimal, and equal sign keys (button).

Problem: I am trying to make it so by pressing the equal sign multiple times after an operation has completed it will do the last operation. Such as the example follows:

Operation: 5+6-3

Answer(equal sign pressed once): 8

Equal sign pressed twice: 8-3 = 5 (this does not occur in my code and cant seem to find out why)

The last operation in this case would be "-3"

The code is below, I took our most of the functions that and bits of code that does not cause the issue as the code I have is about 200 lines. (the code below is about 80 lines)

Code:

```
var keys = document.querySelectorAll('#calculator span');
var operators = ['+', '-', 'x', '÷'];
var input;
var inputValue;
var buttonValue;
var equalOnce = false;
var decimalAdd = false;
var lastOperation;

readIn(keys, input, inputValue,buttonValue);

function readIn(keys, input, inputValue, key) {
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].onclick = function(e) {
      input = document.querySelector('.screen');
      inputValue = input.innerHTML;
      key = this.innerHTML;
      keyPressed(key, inputValue, input);
    }
  }
}

//clears screen and input
function clearScreen(input){}

 //calculates all math functions within the equation.
function evalulated(lastCharacter, equations, operator, input){
      //replaces x with * and ÷ with /
      equations = equations.replace(/x/g, '*').replace(/÷/g, '/');
      //checks last character and removes if its an decimal or operator
      if(operator.indexOf(lastCharacter) > -1 || lastCharacter == '.')
        equations = equations.replace(/.$/, '');
      if(equations){
        input.innerHTML = eval(equations);
      }
      return;
    }

//finds the last operator and take the operator and the last digits/number used with the operrator and save it into lastOperation
function findLastEquation(equation, lastOperation){
  var plusLastIndex = equation.lastIndexOf('+');
  var subLastIndex = equation.lastIndexOf('-');
  var divideLastIndex = equation.lastIndexOf('÷');
  var multipleLastIndex = equation.lastIndexOf('x');

  if(plusLastIndex > subLastIndex && plusLastIndex > divideLastIndex  && plusLastIndex > multipleLastIndex){
    lastOperation = equation.slice(plusLastIndex, equation.length);
  }else if(subLastIndex > plusLastIndex && subLastIndex > divideLastIndex  && subLastIndex > multipleLastIndex){
    lastOperation = equation.slice(subLastIndex, equation.length);
  } else if(divideLastIndex > plusLastIndex && divideLastIndex > subLastIndex  && divideLastIndex > multipleLastIndex){
    lastOperation = equation.slice(divideLastIndex, equation.length);
  } else if(multipleLastIndex > plusLastIndex && multipleLastIndex > subLastIndex  && multipleLastIndex > divideLastIndex){
    lastOperation = equation.slice(multipleLastIndex, equation.length);
  }else{
    lastOperation = 0;
  }
  return lastOperation;
}

function keyPressed(key, inputValue, input) {
  var equation;
  var lastChar;
  var newEquation;

  if(key == 'C') {
    clearScreen(input);
  }
  else if(key == '=') {
    if(equalOnce == false) {
      equalOnce = true;
      equation = inputValue;
      lastOperation = findLastEquation(equation, lastOperation);
    }else {
      equation = equation.concat(lastOperation);
      alert(equation);
    }
    lastChar = equation[equation.length - 1];
    evalulated(lastChar, equation, operators, input);

    decimalAdd = false;
  }
  else if(operators.indexOf(key) > -1) {
    lastChar = inputValue[inputValue.length - 1]; 
    if(operators.indexOf(lastChar) > -1 && inputValue.length > 1) {}
    equalOnce = false;
  }
  //adds a decimal to input, adds a '0.' if no integer was before it
  else if(key == '.' && equalOnce == false) {
    if(decimalAdd == false) {}
      input.innerHTML += key;
      decimalAdd = true;
    }
    equalOnce = false;
  }
  else {          
    if(equalOnce == true){
      clearScreen(input);
    }
    if(key == '.'){}
    input.innerHTML += key;
  }
```

}

Any help or suggestion will be great! Thank you in advance!

Comment: As an aside, your code is susceptible to XSS attacks. You execute `eval` on user input; never do this

Comment: could you create snippet, please =)

Comment: @NickZuber I am not sure what you mean by XSS attacks, i thought xss attack is when a user a code into an input and it would run the background without the website owner knowledge? would setting a variable to eval and then put the change the input to the variable work instead of straight forward to execute eval on user input?

Comment: @Brandon Try writing `alert()` as input in your program

Comment: @NickZuber is it honestly a big deal to allow the user to XSS themselves? I mean, open a console, and type `alert()` the same thing happens here, right? If this content were saved, and run on other user's pages, then you would have something to talk about, but as it stands, this is no different than a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put the statement:

```
equation = inputValue;
```

outside of the if else statement in the if(key == '='){}
worked fine now.